# Integrating Host Machine Metrics (CPU, RAM) with .NET API Using OpenTelemetry

Tags: .net, open-telemetry

I am currently working with a .NET API and have successfully integrated OpenTelemetry for collecting metrics and traces. My objective now is to extend this functionality to include the collection of host machine metrics, specifically CPU and RAM usage.

Is there a way to integrate CPU and RAM metrics collection for the host machine using OpenTelemetry in a .NET environment? If so, could someone provide guidance or point me towards the relevant documentation or examples?

Any insights or advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

After exploring the official OpenTelemetry documentation and resources, I haven't found clear information on whether OpenTelemetry supports the collection of host-machine metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to gather host metrics is using the OpenTelemetry Collector.

https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/installation/

There is a specific component called the hostmetricsreceiver that will pull the data on the host machine and push that to the place you want.

In short, you don't use .NET to get them, it's not the application that's pulling them, it's a separate service that is language agnostic.